# Different redis databases for cache and sessions in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-4, redis

I am trying to move away from file cache and use redis instead. I can get it working using the same redis database for cache and sessions but this means I cannot clear the application cache without losing all sessions so I am wanting to run the two on different databases on the same server. My configs are as follows:

```
 database.php

      'redis' => array(

          'cluster' => false,

              'default' => array('host' => 'redisserverip', 'port' => 6379, 'database' => 0),
              'session' => array('host' => 'redisserverip', 'port' => 6379, 'database' => 1),

          ),

 cache.php

      'driver' => 'redis',
      'connection' => null,

 session.php

      'driver' => 'redis',          
      'connection' => 'session',
```

This is not working as both the application cache and sessions are being saved into the 1st database when it should be shared accross the 0th and 1st database. Is this a bug in Laravel or a problem with my config?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its a bug, but the options for making a connection to a Redis server is never being introduced as I can see in [Redis Class for Laravel 4.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php)

```
protected function createSingleClients(array $servers)
{
    $clients = array();
    foreach ($servers as $key => $server)
    {
        $clients[$key] = new Client($server);
    }
    return $clients;
}
```

While if you compare it with the [Redis Class for Laravel 5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php) , the options for each server is passed so the feature is supported.

```
protected function createSingleClients(array $servers)
{
    $clients = array();
    $options = $this->getClientOptions($servers);
    foreach ($servers as $key => $server)
    {
        $clients[$key] = new Client($server, $options);
    }
    return $clients;
}
```

I am taking into consideration, that in your example you are looking for the `No cluster` option.

Comment: are you suggesting if I change cluster to true I may be able to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, am just pointing out that those methods I am showing are to connect to single servers.

Comment: The suggestion would be to update the framework http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The **connection** parameter has nothing to do with **redis**, as stated on the config file [cache.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.11/app/config/cache.php#L33)

> When using the "**database**" cache driver you may specify the
>   connection that should be used to store the cached items. When this
>   option is **null** the **default** database connection will be utilized for
>   cache.

Comment: In session.php you can specify the name of the redis connection. ""When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a connection that should be used to manage these sessions.""

Comment: true but this in the redis you cant specify the name of the connection, check the session comment https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.11/app/config/session.php#L50